# AppEngine: only loading necessary jars

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar

I'd like to include a template library for generating user emails.  However, only a tiny percentage of requests require this jar.  I'd like to kick off a task that will load the jar and then send my email in the background, returning to the user ASAP.

How can I defer loading the jar until it's required?

It's occurred to me to upload multiple versions of the app, one with the jar and other email utilities, and one without.  I'd be sad to lose the way I currently use versions, though, which is to specify incremental improvements.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Instead of having jar in lib, leave that some where else and use custom classloader? Something we do while database driver load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible I'm afraid, although you could use multiple versions of you app in the way you suggest but also use versions for incremental improvements. Since you can use any string as the version "number" for your app, you could have "mail-1" and "1" as the two copies of version 1. You end up having half the number of versions available, but you can still use them for both purposes.